# how can we use lock APIs in infinispan without using transaction

Tags: configuration, locking, infinispan

We can configure locking in infinispan_config.xml file. So during coding can we use the lock without using the transaction for get and put method into cache ?

OR

Can I use locking in nontransactional cache of inifinispan?

i.e I would like to know if there is any method to unlock a key locked by cache.getAdvancedCache.lock(key) without using transaction manager commit  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the locking API without transactions in Infinispan.